# Deploy contract on polygon, success on mumbai but fail on mainnet

Tags: solidity, polygon, smartcontracts, hardhat

I have deployed the same contract (created with openzepplin wizard) using hardhat on the testnet and the mainnet of Polygon. However, the result is different and something seems to go wrong when I deploy on the mainnet.

Here you can see the contract deployed on the testnet mumbai: https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0xe286e267c6ed4cbf3cf42bbb7fea05ec8b92da79#code

Everything looks ok.

But on the mainnet, I can't find the "Read as proxy" and "Write as proxy" tabs.

https://polygonscan.com/address/0xe286e267c6ed4cbf3cf42bbb7fea05ec8b92da79#readContract

And when I click on the different options. Like the one to retrieve the symbol or the contract name, I don't see anything on the mainnet while I see "IEIG" on mubai explorer for the symbol.

When deploying to the mainnet with hardhat, I also got this error that I didn't get the mumbai. despite the fact that the contract seems to have been deployed "correctly".

```bash
/Users/estalella/Documents/gitlab/crypto-nft/final/hardhat/node_modules/@openzeppelin/upgrades-core/src/deployment.ts:180
      throw new InvalidDeployment(deployment);
            ^
Error: No contract at address 0x42c6C675eEa86798c2A6291Daa653D592787D6c1 (Removed from manifest)
    at waitAndValidateDeployment (/Users/estalella/Documents/gitlab/crypto-nft/final/hardhat/node_modules/@openzeppelin/upgrades-core/src/deployment.ts:180:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at fetchOrDeployGeneric (/Users/estalella/Documents/gitlab/crypto-nft/final/hardhat/node_modules/@openzeppelin/upgrades-core/src/impl-store.ts:70:5)
    at deployImpl (/Users/estalella/Documents/gitlab/crypto-nft/final/hardhat/node_modules/@openzeppelin/hardhat-upgrades/src/utils/deploy-impl.ts:96:22)
    at deployProxyImpl (/Users/estalella/Documents/gitlab/crypto-nft/final/hardhat/node_modules/@openzeppelin/hardhat-upgrades/src/utils/deploy-impl.ts:74:10)
    at Proxy.deployProxy (/Users/estalella/Documents/gitlab/crypto-nft/final/hardhat/node_modules/@openzeppelin/hardhat-upgrades/src/deploy-proxy.ts:35:28)
    at main (/Users/estalella/Documents/gitlab/crypto-nft/final/hardhat/scripts/deployProxy.cjs:16:19)
```

Would anyone be able to help me so that I can solve this error?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I have the same problem with Polygon.
When I use a proxy contract on testnet it works fine, but when I use it on mainnet it failed, as if the data storage in proxy contract differs from the main contract.

How did you finally fix it?